# javascript not executing on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my html:

```
<head>
<link href="/prop-view.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        </script>
        <script src="/prop-view.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in my prop-view.js file:

```
$j("<div class='dk-logo'></div>").appendTo("body");
```

The inspector shows no errors. But the image doesn't show up. It does, however, when I copy and paste that line into the console. So... my guess is the js file is running before the document is fully loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the DOM is loaded first by doing this:

```
$j(function() {
    $j("<div class='dk-logo'></div>").appendTo("body");
});
```

This is a shortcut for jQuery's `ready()` function. The code inside is not executed until the `<body>` tag is fully loaded.

Because you were placing the code *before* the `<body>` tag, there was no `<body>` yet to which to append.

Answer (score 3):

You're right. Execute your code on DOM ready.

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
  $j("<div class='dk-logo'></div>").appendTo("body");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When prop-view.js is executed, the body is not yet available.
Just attach the script-tags at the bottom of the body-tag. The page loads faster and the script will run as expected

```
<body>
   ...
   <script ...></script>
</body>
```